# `stack test` not returning any results

Tags: haskell, testing, haskell-stack

I have a stack project set up but when I run `stack test` I do not get any output or errors. However if I run the test file directly `runhaskell Tests.hs`, I get my desired results.

```
c:\storeCredit>stack test
storeCredit-0.1.0.0: test (suite: storeCredit-test)


c:\storeCredit>
```

This is my .cabal file:

```
name:                storeCredit
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     StoreCredit
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , split
                     , containers

  default-language:    Haskell2010



test-suite storeCredit-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Tests.hs
  build-depends:       base

                     , hspec
                     , split
                     , directory
                     , filepath
                     , containers
                     , storeCredit

  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

out put from `stack test -v`

```
c:\storeCredit>stack test -v
Version 1.3.2, Git revision 3f675146590da4f3edf768b89355f798229da2a5 x86_64 hpack-0.15.0
2017-08-07 16:15:23.708484: [debug] Checking for project config at: C:\storeCredit\stack.yaml
@(Stack\Config.hs:863:9)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.709485: [debug] Loading project config file stack.yaml
@(Stack\Config.hs:881:13)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.728491: [debug] Trying to decode C:\sr\build-plan-cache\x86_64-windows\lts-9.0.cache
@(Data\Store\VersionTagged.hs:68:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.745500: [debug] Success decoding C:\sr\build-plan-cache\x86_64-windows\lts-9.0.cache
@(Data\Store\VersionTagged.hs:72:13)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.762504: [debug] Using standard GHC build
@(Stack\Setup.hs:597:9)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.769506: [debug] Getting global package database location
@(Stack\GhcPkg.hs:55:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.773514: [debug] Asking GHC for its version
@(Stack\Setup\Installed.hs:103:13)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.774515: [debug] Getting Cabal package version
@(Stack\GhcPkg.hs:189:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.786519: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.788791: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc.EXE --numeric-version
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.800797: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.839811: [debug] Process finished in [92m48ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc.EXE --numeric-version
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.888835: [debug] Process finished in [92m100ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.919846: [debug] Process finished in [92m109ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db field --simple-output Cabal version
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.921846: [debug] Resolving package entries
@(Stack\Setup.hs:252:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.924848: [debug] Starting to execute command inside EnvConfig
@(Stack\Runners.hs:163:18)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.925849: [debug] Parsing the cabal files of the local packages
@(Stack\Build\Source.hs:298:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.929851: [debug] Parsing the targets
@(Stack\Build\Source.hs:235:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.945857: [debug] Start: getPackageFiles C:\storeCredit\storeCredit.cabal
@(Stack\Package.hs:250:21)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.954862: [debug] Finished in 7ms: getPackageFiles C:\storeCredit\storeCredit.cabal
@(Stack\Package.hs:250:21)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.965864: [debug] Finding out which packages are already installed
@(Stack\Build\Installed.hs:68:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:23.969865: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.056905: [debug] Process finished in [92m86ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --global --no-user-package-db dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.085421: [debug] Ignoring package xhtml due to wanting version 3000.2.2 instead of 3000.2.1
@(Stack\Build\Installed.hs:191:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.086923: [debug] Ignoring package haskeline due to wanting version 0.7.4.0 instead of 0.7.3.0
@(Stack\Build\Installed.hs:191:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.089927: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapshots\62cfb14b\pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.175466: [debug] Process finished in [92m84ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\sr\snapshots\62cfb14b\pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.187961: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\storeCredit\.stack-work\install\6c953ab2\pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.255986: [debug] Process finished in [92m65ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --user --no-user-package-db --package-db C:\storeCredit\.stack-work\install\6c953ab2\pkgdb dump --expand-pkgroot
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.264989: [debug] Constructing the build plan
@(Stack\Build\ConstructPlan.hs:159:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.275500: [debug] Checking if we are going to build multiple executables with the same name
@(Stack\Build.hs:196:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.287968: [debug] Executing the build plan
@(Stack\Build\Execute.hs:454:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.291968: [debug] Getting global package database location
@(Stack\GhcPkg.hs:55:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.292968: [debug] Run process: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.363995: [debug] Process finished in [92m68ms[0m: C:\Users\Matthias\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.0.2\bin\ghc-pkg.EXE --no-user-package-db list --global
@(System\Process\Read.hs:306:3)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.377005: [info] storeCredit-0.1.0.0: test (suite: storeCredit-test)
@(Stack\Build\Execute.hs:826:23)

2017-08-07 16:15:24.380008: [debug] Creating process: C:\storeCredit\.stack-work\dist\ca59d0ab\build\storeCredit-test\storeCredit-test.exe
@(System\Process\Run.hs:139:5)
2017-08-07 16:15:24.407025: [info]
@(Stack\Build\Execute.hs:1449:52)
```

**SOLVED:**

The problem was that in my Tests.hs file, I have a function which gets files in the directory and uses those as inputs and outputs for testing. It contains the line:

`dir <- getDirectoryContents =<<  getCurrentDirectory`

This was obviously fine if run from with the same directory as the Test.hs file i.e. `\test`. which is why `runhaskell Test.hs` works. However, `stack test` is run from the parent folder to `test` and I had to change the path being read.

So changing to:

`dir <- getDirectoryContents =<< ((++ "\\test") <$> getCurrentDirectory)`

fixed the prblem

Comment: Please add a [MCVE].

Comment: Try `stack test -v` and paste the output here.

Comment: @Sibi  I have added the output

Comment: matthias: As @leftaroundabout said, it would be useful it you would create a minimal reproducible example also.

Comment: @Sibi i actually figured out the problem and it was a simple path problem in my test file :(. It makes this post rather trivial and silly. Should I just delete it now as it does not really have any benefit to anyone?

Comment: Post the answer - it is always helpful. Even if unrelated.